# How to setup a development environment with vagrant and javaee

Tags: jakarta-ee, vagrant

I am working on a jee webapp and I have decided to develop my app on a vm with configured with vagrant.

How can I setup eclipse so it uses the tomcat in the vm?
Or do I need to mount the deployed directory? It seems like my eclipse deploys
to the current directory :

`C:\Users\username\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`

So I just could share this directory with the vm.

Or is there another way?

The question is how can I setup vagrant and javaee so I can debug and test my app in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do that - I would go with

1. share folder for your project (not the deployed one but your actual project folder)
2. deploy your app on your VM - so build and push the war file in Tomcat for example (or any app server you use)
3. For debugging, you will use remote debugging (so use fix IP in vagrant so you can connect from eclipse)